# Is it possible to invoke the auto row sorter in a jtable

Tags: java, swing, sorting, jtable, tablerowsorter

is there anyway to invoke the auto row sorter in a jtable that is created by using

```
setAutoCreateRowSorter(true);
```

i'm trying to get it to sort by a default column without the user having to click on on the column header.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
table.getRowSorter().toggleSortOrder(modelColumnIndex)
```

Answer (score 8):

```
TableRowSorter rowSorter = (TableRowSorter) table.getRowSorter();
List<SortKey> keys = new ArrayList<SortKey>();
SortKey sortKey = new SortKey(2, SortOrder.ASCENDING);//column index 2
keys.add(sortKey);
rowSorter.setSortKeys(keys);
rowSorter.sort();
```

Comment: curious: setSortKeys is documented to trigger a sort (if the given list is different than the current), no explicit sort() needed - or have you found corner cases where it was?

Comment: I haven't had problems before. I just didn't read the API correctly and always added the sort :(

Answer (score 2):

> i'm trying to get it to sort by a default column without the user
>   having to click on on the column header.

I think you have to use [setSortsOnUpdates(true)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/DefaultRowSorter.html#setSortsOnUpdates%28boolean%29) method from [TableRowSorter](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/table/TableRowSorter.html) class.

Comment: that's not an answer to the question as I understand it, could be me mis-understanding, though :-)